# TFS Shelving - Forgot to untick "Preserve pending changes locally"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've just shelved a bunch of changes. I forgot to untick the "Preserve pending changes locally" checkbox...

How can I effectively revert my changes to how they were before I started work on them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just "undo checkout" on the files you shelved.
(As long as you are *sure* that they are safely stored in a shelveset)

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I did.....
Although, I actually re-shelved the stuff again first, then deleted the original shelveset

Comment: and a +1 for making sure that they are safely stored in a shelveset.... I checked at least 3 times

Comment: Always best to be sure :-) (and if you don't trust VS/TFS, then you can always take a manual copy of the files for backup purposes too)